# Как увеличить время отклика ключа API в pyowm

Tags: python

Сделал простенькую программу что бы узнать погоду. И проблема вот в чем. Если время отклика ключа API больше 10 секунд, то выдает ошибку TimeoutError: API call timeouted. Вопрос: как увеличить время отклика?
Вот часть кода:

```
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'

owm = OWM("APY key", config_dict)
place = input("В каком городе?: ")
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.weather
```

Comment: mgr.weather_at_place(place, timeout=60)

Comment: Не совсем понял как именно использовать данную переменную, если просто добавлять  timeout=60) после "place" то выдает ошибку о не известном имени